# How to index array data type from mongodb to elasticsearch using logstash

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash

We were trying to index data from mongodb using logstash but we were unable to index array data type fields alone, also there were no errors in the log file.

Comment: Were you trying to index those arrays on a parent document? Also, what  is the data type of the array values?

Comment: Try to launch logstash with the -verbose parameter and see if there are any kind of warning.

Comment: @Miek,yes, fields that are single valued is getting indexed, but arrays are not getting indexed. Array fieldtype is string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with MongoDB plugin which we used in logstash.

we added ruby code to the logstash-conf file to get the arrays from log_entry field.

Note: log_entry will have the complete field list and data.